# Symfony2 / Doctrine queries in loops

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, anti-patterns

I'm cleaning up some old code written by someone else because we're having problems with time-outs, especially with customers who are pushing the limits of our system.

I know this is an anti-pattern, and the code is full of variations of this:

```
$userIDs = [100,101,107,208, ...]; // tons of users, but not all users in a company.
$companyID = 4356;

foreach ($userIDs as $id) {
    $user = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Users')
                ->getUser($id, $companyId);          
    $user->removeGroup($group);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
```

It just causes a query for every user, which makes the server time out (profiler shows hundreds of queries). Increasing the timeouts does work, but that solution doesn't scale well... and causes me to take more coffee breaks than is healthy.

What would be the correct, efficient, symfony-ey way to rewrite this into a single update query?

Comment: Tell me how the user's id and company's id are set please.

Comment: From session data and request parameter. I'm still trying to decipher most of it, but it's a controller doing "admin panel" stuff -- coupling permissions, users and groups together. Form on the "group" page has a bunch of checkboxes and dropdowns, where you can add any number of users from the company to that group, and set permissions for various actions. Problem is, some companies have hundreds of users and hundreds of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities :

1. using a query builder with a `whereIn` statement , bound to the array of users id and a `andWhere` with the company id
2. if the goal is to do a DELETE, and you don't make any other use of the entity after that, you can use a crafted DQL request.

if needed I can edit and put some more helpers.

Comment: Awesome, this works great!

Now I just have one problematic loop left, which has a second loop inside it. It loops through all the users, then loops through all the currently associated groups (FOSuserbundle) to remove them, then reassign the new group. By removing the outer loop and doing a where IN(), im down to 1000 instead of a million queries (1000^2). Do you know if there is a way to do $user->removeallgroups();?

Comment: I don't know exactly what "groups" is , but if it's an ArrayCollection, then you can do the removeAllGroups by  using  $user->getGroups()->clear();  I think.

Comment: Yup, arraycollection. But I still get a lot of queries, as part of it is still inside a loop. 

See this example: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MwDqugzw

The "getUsersFromArray" thing is a function in the repository I quickly added so I can grab pass an array of user IDs, and select them using "->where("u.id IN(:userids) AND ..." etc.