# Symfony/Doctrine remove query in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is a bit of a followup on my previous question:
[Symfony2 / Doctrine queries in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578723/symfony2-doctrine-queries-in-loops). I thought it would be better to post this as a separate question though, as the first part has been solved.

I've updated some old query code in our product, because it was causing timeouts. I'm not very used to the whole Symfony/Doctrine/Repository/Entity concept, it's pretty confusing and convoluted in my (limited) experience), but I'm trying to fix it as best I can.

At first, the getRepository was inside a nested foreach loop, so I made a getUsersFromArray function in the repository so it doesn't have to loop over that (causing literally a million queries). I accomplished that by using a where IN(:ids) statement. That helps a lot, at least it doesn't time out any more.

I still have a foreach loop left over, which removes groups from users, so with a 1000 users that's still a 1000 queries... should be doable in a single query right?

```
$usersWhoShouldNotHaveGroup = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:User')
                                 ->getUsersFromArray($session['usersNotHaveGroup'], $user->getCompany());

foreach ($usersWhoShouldHaveGroup as $u) {
    $u->removeGroup($group);
    $em->persist($u);
}
$em->flush();
```

With the removeGroup function being defined in the default FOSUserBundle:

```
public function removeGroup(GroupInterface $group)
{
    if ($this->getGroups()->contains($group)) {
        $this->getGroups()->removeElement($group);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

And groups being defined like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Something\AdminBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;
```

(user_group table just has 2 columns, user ids coupled to group ids, user can only be in a single group at a time)

My current code is listed [here](http://labs.octivi.com/mastering-symfony2-performance-doctrine/) (point 3) as an antipattern, although I wouldn't know how to implement his solution in my case.

What I do not understand, according to the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#deleting-an-object), the actual queries should only be called once it does the $em->flush()?

Then why does the profiler still show a 1000 queries during the foreach loop?

How could I remedy this?

Comment: Is relation bi-directional? If yes, try to delete users on group side and do `persist($group)` out of loop.

Comment: Does `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")` in the group entity mean it's bidirectional? And then I should use removeuser() from that entity inside a foreach loop right?

Comment: Yes, it is bidirectional. Yes, use it in loop. After loop try use persist. Hope, it works.